# How do I check if the arrays items are the same and in the same (even rotated) order?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

Suppose to have an array like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

and another one like this (rotated):

```
[3,4,5,6,1,2]
```

Is there any easy way to tell that they are equal or shall I write a specific method to compare them?

**EDIT:** of course, the first array should NOT be equal with:

```
[4,3,5,6,1,2]    // 4 and 3 are swapped
[1,2,4,3,5,6]    // 4 and 3 are swapped
```

or

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  // too many items
```

Comment: There is no built in way to do that. You'd have to process the arrays in some way.

Comment: What if items are not *rotated* but *swaped*, i.e. `{1, 2, 3, 4}` vs. `{1, 3, 2, 4}` (note, that items `2` and `3` are swaped)? Are these arrays equal or not?

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Not

Comment: You will have to write it yourself. I assume you'll have no difficulty doing so, but if you get stuck you can update the question.

Comment: Use the map(x=>x) method to check to see if the array items are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have an array `{a, b, c, .., z}` and we want to find if it equals to `{A, B, ..., Z}` we can turn the problem into equivalent

> Having `abc...z` string check if `ABC...ZABC...Z` string contains `abc...z`

To solve it we can use efficient [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) **KMP** (`t ~ O(n)`) or
if arrays are *not very long* use easy to implement naive prefix comparisons (`t ~ O(n ** 2)` in the *worst case*):

```
    private static bool MyEquals(int[] left, int[] right)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
            return true;

        if (left is null || right is null)
            return false;

        if (left.Length != right.Length)
            return false;

        for (int start = 0; start < right.Length; ++start)
        {
            bool found = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; ++i)
                if (right[(start + i) % right.Length] != left[i])
                {
                    found = false;

                    break;
                }

            if (found)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Note that

```
    left.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(right.OrderBy(x => x))
```

*doesn't work*; the counter example is `{1, 2, 3, 4}` vs. `{1, 3, 2, 4}` which should be *not equal* when the code above returns `true`.

You can [fiddle with my KMP implementation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BlJNYk) as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, we check the `first item of the second` list in the first list. If it is found, we rotate it by the size of the index and compare two list:

```
    public bool listCompare(List<int>  l1, List<int>  l2)
    {
        int index = l1.FindIndex(a => a ==  l2[0]);
        if(index==-1) 
            return false;
        for(int i=0;i< index;i++)
        {
            int item = l1[0];
            l1.RemoveAt(0);
            l1.Add(item);
        }
        if(l1.SequenceEqual(l2))
              return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

The above solution is correct if the lists do not have duplicate items. If there is a duplicate item, all states must be checked. As follows:

```
    public bool listCompare2(List<int> l1, List<int> l2)
    {
        var tempList = l1.Select(item => item).ToList(); 

        var indexs = l1.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
              .Where(x => x.x == l2[0])
              .Select(x => x.i).ToArray();
        for (int n = 0; n < indexs.Length; n++)
        {
            int rotateSize = indexs[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < rotateSize ; i++)
            {
                int item = l1[0];
                l1.RemoveAt(0);
                l1.Add(item);
            }
            if (l1.SequenceEqual(l2))
                return true;
            l1 = tempList;
        }

        return false;
    }
```